# Problema al instalar drive de adaptador usb wifit tp-link TL-WN823N en sistema operativo linux elementary os

Tags: linux, redes

Hola chicos quisiera saber como puedo instalar correctamente el driver para el adaptar usb de wifi tp-link version TW-WN823N en linux en la distribucion de elementary os poseo problemas como los siguientes

Al intentar buscar el id dentro de los usb conectados a mi ordenador bajo la linea de comando lsusb no me lo detecta  para asi mismo descargar su contrador y instaladar los headers pertenecientes al no puedo por no saber la versio y al intentarlo instalar como lo dice el manual me da demasiados errores

Comment: Supuestamente ese dispositivo tiene drivers dispoibles para Linux . Puedes descargarlo y encontrar las instrucciones de instalación en https://www.tp-link.com/us/download/TL-WN823N.html#Driver

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve cierto problema con dos tarjetas tp-link, la tl-wn8200n la cual me toco utilizar a la "fuerza" el driver para windows con ndiswrapper y la tl-wn725n, esta ultima tiene soporte nativo por el kernel con el modulo rtl8192eu, tengo entendido que a la tl-wn823n se le dio soporte desde el kernel 4.8.

En el sistema linux que poseo, la solución seria re-compilar el kernel activando ese modulo, tu eres de elementary OS, debes poder instalar ese modulo por aparte desde los repositorios o compilarlo dinamicamente con DKMS.

Busca la solución para tu sistema que a pesar de ser linux varia un poco entre las diferentes distros, ya que la gestión de paquetes es independiente entre cada una, pero el modulo que gestiona ese dispositivo es el rtl8192eu.